# neo4j cypher parse and load XML

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to load the following Equipment.XML into neo4j database -

```
<NetworkEntity>
        <Equipment>
                <Name>IPTC.net/ABC12345</Name>
                <Type>CHASSIS</Type>
                <SubType>Nokia 7750</SubType>
        </Equipment>
        <Equipment>
                <Name>IPTC.net/ABC12345/Shelf-1</Name>
                <Type>SHELF</Type>
                <SubType>Nokia 7750</SubType>
                <Associations>
                        <Association>
                                <Target>
                                        <EntityName>IPTC.net/ABC12345</EntityName>
                                        <EntityType>Equipment</EntityType>
                                </Target>
                                <RelationshipType>RESIDES_ON</RelationshipType>
                                <Features>
                                        <Feature>
                                                <Name>Feat1</Name>
                                                <Value>123</Value>
                                        </Feature>
                                </Features>
                        </Association>
                </Associations>
        </Equipment>
</NetworkEntity>
```

I have written the following cypher procedure so far -

```
call apoc.load.xml("file:///opt/home/neo4j/NEO4JINSTANCE1/neo4j-enterprise-3.0.1/import/Equipment.xml")
        yield value as ne UNWIND ne._children AS eqs
        FOREACH( eq IN eqs |
        FOREACH( child IN eq["_children"] |
        CREATE (:SPAEquipment {name: child["_text"]})))
        RETURN *;
```

But it is considering each property of the Equipment tag as a separate SPAEquipment. Hence Name, Type and SubType - each is getting created as a SPAEquipment instead of three properties of the same SPAEquipment. So instead of children I should use different tags. Also I am not able to create the association between the equipments quite correctly.

So, basically I need to create the different equipments in the database with the corresponding properties and also I need to create the relationships between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with load_xml but I think neo4j is doing exactly what you are asking.

You have the CREATE on the child of the Equipment. 
You are saying: 
    For each  get the children, 
    For each _child
       CREATE SPEquipment ...

What I think you want is

```
For each <Equipment> 
  CREATE (s:SPAEquipment {id:<maybe with a simple ID here>})
For each _child
  set s.propertyName=child["text"]
```

However, I am not sure how apoc.load.xml does that 
The only way I have been able to get the children is as an array of pairs (_type,_text) and I can't seem to figure out how to do anything with that.

```
call apoc.load.xml("file:///Volumes/Data/neo4j-enterprise-  3.0.3/import/myXML.xml") yield value as ne UNWIND ne._children AS eqs
RETURN eqs, [attr IN eqs._children WHERE attr._type IN
   ['Name','Type','SubType'] | [attr._type, attr._text]] as pairs



╒══════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════╕
│eqs                           │pairs                         │
╞══════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════╡
│{_type: Equipment, id: 01, _ch│[[Name, IPTC.net/ABC12345], [T│
│ildren: [{_type: Name, _text: │ype, CHASSIS], [SubType, Nokia│
│IPTC.net/ABC12345}, {_type: Ty│ 7750]]                       │
│pe, _text: CHASSIS}, {_type: S│                              │
│ubType, _text: Nokia 7750}]}  │                              │
├──────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
```

[...]
Note: I created id attributes on my sample, you won't have those.

Comment: Hi @pwsaker: Many thanks for the quick response. I have formulated the following -
`... FOREACH (eq IN eqs |
            CREATE (e.NSEquipment))
        FOREACH (child IN eq["_children"] |
                set e.NSEquipment.propertyName=child["text"])
        FOREACH (child IN eq["_children"] |
                Check whether Associations field is present
                If yes, create a RESIDES_ON Relationship with the Target
                And create properties of the Relationship
        ;`

But I am not able to write down the statements properly.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve this issue using apoc.load.xml. apoc.load.xml breaks the structure into tree and we need to write cypher on top of it. But it was a very complex query and I failed to write it properly.

So I wrote an XSL which would parse the Equipment.xml and build the cypher queries. This is just for our internal use purpose and it's working fine.

Thanks.